# Copy stateflow in a Simulink model

Tags: matlab, simulink, stateflow

I would like to copy a Stateflow chart

The command:

```
Simulink.SubSystem.copyContentsToBlockDiagram(subsys, bdiag)
```

doesn't work on a Stateflow chart alone, rather then only on subsystems.

How could I copy a selected Stateflow to another system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the [Stateflow API](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/api/overview-of-the-stateflow-api.html) (which is different from the Simulink one), in particular this example on [Copy Objects](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/api/copying-objects.html#f13-6062) looks like what you are trying to do.